# Nautilus "open in remote teminal" fails after login

Tags: nautilus, command-line, remote

I have installed open-in-erminal package and now I have "Open in Terminal" and "Open in Remote Terminal" in right click menu in Nautilus.

First one works perfect, but remote does not. It opens terminal, prompts for password, and after I type in a correct password, it terminal just dissapears.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround with the usage of scripts http://dev.umpirsky.com/nautilus-open-in-remote-terminal/