# Nautilus Open in Remote Terminal

Tags: nautilus, scripts

As I already wrote, open-in-erminal package does not work for remote hosts for me [Nautilus "open in remote teminal" fails after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43587/nautilus-open-in-remote-teminal-fails-after-login).

So I decided to try to write my own script to do same thing. I will run it when I'm on location like "sftp://user@myserver.net"

I added script  like this in /home/[user]/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts to get started:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --execute '/usr/bin/ssh user@myserver.net'
```

But, it fails with:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal.
Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/ssh user@myserver.net" (No such file or directory)
```

Any idea why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the quotes are unneeded. Try:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --execute /usr/bin/ssh user@myserver.net
```

Comment: Haha, bingo, thanks! First version was gnome-terminal --execute ssh user@myserver.net, but that failes, so I added absolute path and wrapped with quotes, which was wrong :) Any idea why open-in-terminal package does not work for sftp locations? Хвала још једном земљаче :)

Comment: I don't use that script so I can't really help you. Sorry :/ Nema na čemu :)

Comment: OK, you solved most of it. Now I only need to parse $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI and ssh to current server.

Comment: What I'm trying to do now is gnome-terminal --execute /bin/echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI, but terminal fails to open, even if I replace variable with hardcoded string :o

Comment: You'll probably have more luck by making that into a new question. I've never scripted Nautilus